# Prove $\int^{\infty}_0f'(x)g'(x)\mathrm{dx}$ is an inner product

Tags: real-analysis

We have that our space is the set of all function from $[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ with the following three properties:

1. $f(0)=0$
2. $f$ is abosolutely continuous (hence $f(b)-f(a)=\int^b_af'(x)\mathrm{dx}$)
3. $\int^{\infty}_0[f'(x)]^2\mathrm{dx}\lt \infty$

The dot product is defined as $$\int^{\infty}_0f'(x)g'(x)\mathrm{dx}$$

I would like to show that this is an inner product space. I have shown the second and third property, namely:

(second property) $\langle f,g\rangle =\langle g,f\rangle$

(third property) $\langle \gamma f,g\rangle=\gamma\langle f,g \rangle$ and $\langle f+g, z\rangle = \langle f,z\rangle+\langle g,z\rangle$

Here's my attempt to prove the first property ($\langle f,f\rangle=0 \Leftrightarrow f=0$):

$$\langle f,f\rangle = \int^{\infty}_0[f'(x)]^2\mathrm{dx}=0$$

Since $[f'(x)]^2$ is a nonnegative function, the only way the above integrand can equal $0$ is if $[f'(x)]^2=0$, i.e., $f'(x)=0,\forall x\in [0,\infty)$. I.e. $f$ is a constant function. Since $f(0)=0$, this means that $f$ cannot take any other value otherwise the above equality would not be true, hence $f=0 \forall x\in [0,\infty)$

Would this be correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You can only conclude that $f'(x) = 0$ for almost every $x \in [0, \infty)$. But the rest is correct.

Comment: @Mason the functions are a fortiori continuous, so we can say $f'(x) = 0$ at *all* $x \in [0, \infty)$.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Absolutely continuous functions are only differentiable almost everywhere, so it isn't clear what $f'$ means. I was assuming that $f'$ is a particular choice of the equivalence class of $f'$ in $L^1$.

Comment: @Mason Ah okay. That makes sense. I was wondering what I was missing. Then I think ehsan's post applies (though I think it has a typo), in which case we may still conclude $f = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $int_0^\infty f'(u)^2 du = 0$ then $f'(x)^2 = 0$ almost everywhere. But still you can conclude that $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^\infty f'(u) du = 0$. You can also use cauchy schwarz inequality:
$$
\Big(\int_0^T f'(u) du)^2 \leq (T\int_0^T f'(u)^2 du\Big) = 0
$$